# Binding event to function Coffeescript. Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, haml

I am trying to fetch a JSON on OnChange event. And making changes to the existing haml page.
My aim is to populate another select field with the json values. At the moment I am just trying to print a message that json was fetched. But I get no change in the html.

In the network tab of the console, I see that the URL request is being made, and a 304 response is returned. I can also see the json in the response.

```
events:
    "submit form" : "onSubmit"
    "change [name=repository]" : "onChange"

  onChange: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    name = @$("[name=repository]").val()
    localStorage['new_issue_last_repo'] = name
    token = localStorage['oauth2_github']['accessToken']
    @model = new Assignees(name)
    console.log 'Printttttt'
    @model.fetch {headers : @token},
      success: (model) =>
        @$('.assignee').html("<span>Fetched assignees</span>")
      error: =>
        @$('.assignee').html("<span>Failed to fetch assignees :(</span>")
```

The haml file looks like this.

```
.message
.assignee
%form
  %section.repo-select
    %select{name: 'repository'}
      - for repository in @repositories.models
        - full_name = repository.get('full_name')
        - if localStorage['new_issue_last_repo'] == repository.get('full_name')
          %option{value: full_name, selected: 'selected'}= repository.get('full_name')
        - else
          %option{value: full_name}= repository.get('full_name')
```

How can I get the .assignee to change once the json is fetched. Also how can I access the json data?

I have a similar function that works. I dont know what I am doing wrong in the onChange function.

```
  onSubmit: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    name = @$("[name=repository]").val()
    localStorage['new_issue_last_repo'] = name
    repository = @repositories.find (r) -> r.get('full_name') == name
    model = new IssueModel({
      body: @$("[name=body]").val()
      title: @$("[name=title]").val()
      assignee: @$("[name=assignee]").val()
      milestone: @$("[name=milestone]").val()
    }, {repository: repository})

    model.save {},
      success: (model) =>
        @badge = new Badge()
        @badge.addIssues(1)
        @$('.message').html("<span>Issue <a href=\"#{model.get("html_url")}\" target=\"_blank\">##{model.get('number')}</a> was created!</span>")
      error: =>
        @$('.message').html("<span>Failed to create issue :(</span>")
```

Comment: @muistooshort Updated the question. Sorry for the vague question, I am still trying to figure out coffeescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that big on HAML but this:

```
%form
  %section.repo-select
    %select{name: 'repository'}
```

should become this HTML:

```
<form>
    <section class="repo-select">
        <select name="repository">
            <!-- ... -->
        </select>
    </section>
</form>
```

right? That means that there is nothing that will match the ID-selector `#repo-select` so of course the handler bound to those events, `onChange`, will never be called.

If you want to get change-events from that `<select>`, then you'll want something like this in your `events`:

```
'change [name=repository]'
```

See [Backbone's `View#delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) and [jQuery's Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) document for details.

As far as your messages go, I think you're a little confused about the difference between the [`Model#save`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save) arguments:

> **save** `model.save([attributes], [options])`

and the [`Model#fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) arguments:

> **fetch** `model.save([options])`

`save` takes two arguments with the callbacks in the second so this works:

```
model.save {},
  success: (model) => ...
  error: => ...
```

but `fetch` only takes one argument and the callbacks should be in that argument so this:

```
@model.fetch {headers : @token},
  success: (model) => ...
  error: => ...
```

won't work as `fetch` won't even see the `success` or `error` callbacks. You'd want to say this:

```
@model.fetch
  headers: @token
  success: (model) => ...
  error: => ...
```

to get all three arguments to `fetch`.

Comment: Did that, I was actually using 'change select' which worked till now because i had only one select element. Thanks for the info.

The onChange function is being executed, I can see fetch calls to the api when I select something, but the message is still now shown.

Comment: What message? Why would you expect it to be shown? Shown where?

Comment: on success and on error of the fetch call, I am trying to show a message on the top of the webpage. (in the .assignee class)

The similar function below onSubmit does the same with .message class,  and it works. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Have a look at my update, you're calling `fetch` with the wrong arguments.

Comment: Can you post the working code of what you are trying to achieve?